# Trying to resize 2 boxes with js, wont work dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have 2 Divs with in a row, each has slightly different content. I managed to resize them equal with js, the problem is, when it loads the collapsed content, it won't resize to the new size.

This is my try :

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0u0wnzn/8/)

Html:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-content">
      <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>BOX 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">more...</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body background-solid">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">...less</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-content">
      <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>BOX 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">more...</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body background-solid">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">...less</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
    var heightTallest = Math.max.apply(null, $(".col-content").map(function ()
{
return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get());
$('.col-content').css({ height: heightTallest + 'px' });
```

CSS:

```
.col-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(5, 47, 90, 0.8);
  border-width: medium;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to resize them **both to have the same height**? Or resize them **individually**, according to their content?

Comment: Why no make `overflow:scroll` instead of `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: @typologist I basically want them to have the same height and when the inner content is loaded with "more" only the box extended box should resize . when i close it with "less" it should go back to the normal size.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx yes i tried that but it doesn't look so nice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min-height` css property.

Now, on your JS do this:

`$('.col-content').css({ "min-height": heightTallest + 'px' });`

What happened here? This means that your div will obey the minimum height of whatever value you set to it, but will have any height greater than the min-height you provided.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/hor9nygo/)

Comment: Thanks a lot that looks like the solution, i am going to try it out right now.

Comment: It will work trust me ;) :D @Karle

Comment: awesome ..u are a hero , thank u :)

Comment: one quick question, i am new to js ..i tried to do the same with 2 rows, and different content it all works...just the js is a bit ugly .. tried to nest both funtions into one but it didnt work ...isnt there a way to make it nicer ?              https://jsfiddle.net/x0u0wnzn/23/

Comment: Hi @Karle please check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/j9k2L7ph/